# Why is reading from Tensorflow Record files so slow for big tensors?

Tags: python-3.6, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I have a few tensorflow (v2.1.1) record files, with about a 200K examples in each. 
Each tensor is 300x1500 in dimension. Each tfrecord file would be about 60GB. 
When trying to read a batch of size 2048, the read latency encountered is 70-80 seconds. Not quite sure what is wrong. 
The input is totally preprocessed so except deserialisation, there are no other transformations.

Even while reading a single example, I see a 100-150 ms latency which is again too much.

```
import tensorflow as tf

def load_dataset():
    filenames = ["A.tfrecord", "B.tfrecord", "C.tfrecord", "D.tfrecord"]
    print("Training on record names: ", filenames)
    raw_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames, buffer_size=100, num_parallel_reads=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
    parsed_dataset = raw_dataset.map(parse_example,
                                     num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
    return parsed_dataset


def parse_example(serialized_example):
    parse_dict = {
        'X': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
        'X_lengths': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
        'Y': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
        'Y_lengths': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
    }

    example = tf.io.parse_single_example(serialized_example, parse_dict)

    X = tf.io.parse_tensor(example['X'], out_type=tf.float32)
    X.set_shape([300, 1500])

    X_lengths = tf.io.parse_tensor(example['X_lengths'], out_type=tf.int32)
    X_lengths.set_shape([])

    Y = tf.io.parse_tensor(example['Y'], out_type=tf.int32)
    Y.set_shape([40])

    Y_lengths = tf.io.parse_tensor(example['Y_lengths'], out_type=tf.int32)
    Y_lengths.set_shape([])

    return X, X_lengths, Y, Y_lengths


def get_dataset(strategy=None):
    dataset = load_dataset()

    dataset = dataset.batch(2048, drop_remainder=True)

    dataset = dataset.prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)

    dataset = strategy.experimental_distribute_dataset(dataset)

    return dataset
```

My dataset object is provided by the get_dataset method. Which I am using in my training loop:

```
while True:
    train_dataset = get_dataset(strategy=mirrored_strategy)
    before_next_batch_time = time.time()
    for batch in train_dataset:
        print("Time taken for next batch: {} ".format(time.time() - before_next_batch_time))
        x, x_lengths, y, y_lengths = batch

        before_train_step = time.time()

        mean_train_loss = train_step(x, x_lengths, y, y_lengths)

        print("Time taken for train step: {}".format(time.time() - before_train_step))
        before_next_batch_time = time.time()
        print("****")
```

Actual run logs:

```
****
Time taken for next batch: 76.75251317024231
Time taken for train step: 2.1996893882751465
****
Time taken for next batch: 76.99043083190918
Time taken for train step: 2.192229747772217
****
Time taken for next batch: 76.46133637428284
Time taken for train step: 2.2198166847229004
****
Time taken for next batch: 76.34514284133911
Time taken for train step: 2.1689696311950684
****
Time taken for next batch: 77.19221472740173
Time taken for train step: 2.2315127849578857
****
```

Edit:

The TF record file is kept on a mounted disk on the same vm. There are no network calls, as the distribution is happening within the same vm, this vm has 4 GPUs.

Comment: So, it means for one batch, you would read about 2048*300*1500*4/1024/1024/1024 = ~3.4 GB of data, right? That goes through all the loading and processing and CPU memory. That might just be too much?

Comment: Via `experimental_distribute_dataset`, it would copy that to all clients, right? The clients are other workers on the network? So it copies that 3.4GB of data over your network for every step? Maybe that is slow?

Comment: @Albert The batch size is 2048. So in total there are 2048*300*1500 float32 numbers. And this batch of 2048 is distributed within the vm, which has 4 32GB V100 GPUS, so 512 is the batch size for each local GPU. There are no network calls. The tf-record file is kept on a mounted disk on the same vm.

Comment: Can you try using `parse_example` instead. The documentation states "One might see performance advantages by batching Example protos with parse_example instead of using `parse_single_example` function directly.". Let us know how it goes.

Comment: I am facing a similar issue and would appreciate to see how the problem above was solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try increasing buffer size to some bigger number. From 100 to 10000, for example. It helped me decrease training time by an order of magnitude on dgx-2!